# How to activate VirtualEnv on IDE

Tags: keras, virtualenv, clion

I need to Debug my Project using IDE but It requires to be run on a `virtualenv`. I have created a `virtualenv` on the IDE Clion using this [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-virtual-environment.html):

But I am not able to activate it. Will it get automatically activated, when I run the project? I have tried that also but it is not running.
when I am running it from terminal everything works fine but debugging becomes difficult as I am not much familiar with gdb.
How do I activate my `virtualenv` on IDE??

Comment: you wouldn't use gdb to debug python code anyway

Comment: Its not a python code, Its a c++ project which is using some engine that can only be run on virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to solve this problem. Basically you just have to activate the virtualenv from terminal, using source TargetDir/bin/activate and launch your IDE from there. It is working fine after that.

Comment: That works but there are nicer ways to manage it, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the general question, how to activate a virtualenv on an IDE will probably depend on the specific IDE and are related to how you set up an interpreter.

For Visual Studio instructions are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio

For Visual Studio Code instructions are here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

For CLion instructions are here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html